# React Native Android SDK version not found

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am trying to run react-native using `nx`. But I am getting an error while running the command
`react-native doctor`.

> Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
>
> - Versions found: 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 34.0.0
> - Version supported: Not Found

Please help me to fix this issue. I've been stuck on this for so long.

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: I don't know exactly the steps to solve it, but you need to be looking in exporting the android sdk in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

React native requires Android SDK `version 33`. Install the correct version, see [Install the Android SDK](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=native&platform=android) for details.

> Building a React Native app with native code, requires the Android 13 (Tiramisu) SDK in particular.